# Birds on the trees in the background

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

How do these birds pop up behind the trees on the bottom?

http://grabaperch.com/about

Are they using css with php or what is it?

Comment: What a descriptive title. :)

Comment: Are you serious? how hard is to look at the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using jQuery to animate the birds and trees. There is an animate function that pops the birds out from behind the trees - adjusting the z-index will properly layer elements in that fashion.

Answer (score 6):

They use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

They have some JavaScript code in [perch.js](http://grabaperch.com/assets/js/perch.js) that [animates](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) the birds and the trees.

Comment: @every: Google is simply hosting the juquery file (CDN)

Comment: Loading your javascript from a (reliable) third-party domain can actually decrease the loading time of your site. Browsers can make simultaneous connections to separate sites, though most limit the number of connections you make to the same site when loading a single page.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery

.animate

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

The reason it's *behind* is [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 1):

It is javascript, the code is [here](http://grabaperch.com/assets/js/perch.js)